# Export file generated by a project

Tags: jenkins

I have a Java project that is running as a job on a Jenkins server. The project is generating a file that is being stored locally on the server in the respective project folder. Currently, to get hold of this file, I am logging into the Jenkins server and get it manually. I would like to make this file available for download directly through the Jenkins job somehow. Not sure if there is a way to do that though. Is there a plug in that might add this functionality or is there any other way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archive the file. For a freestyle job, that would be a "Post Build Step". For a pipeline job, use archiveArtifacts.

You definitely don't want to rely it on it being in a workspace on the Jenkins agent machine somewhere. The workspace directories can move and change, or be removed.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate how to archive a file? In "Post Build Step" I didn't find anything that mentions archiving.